# В базу Mysql с помощью программы Qt вставляются данные с id =0

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt, qt5

В базу Mysql с помощью программы Qt вставляются данные и постоянно c 0 id если я его не указываю, вот таблица:

```
 QString table1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, product TEXT, cost    DOUBLE")
```

Там столбцов больше, но это сути не меняет,вот запрос:

```
query->prepare("INSERT INTO table ( product, cost) "
                               "VALUES (:product, :cost)");
query->bindValue(":product", link->product);
query->bindValue(":cost", link->cost);
if(!query->exec()) {
    qDebug() <<"Error Insert";
    return false;
}
```

В таблице появляется запись c id=0. Кстати если использовать это:

```
int ret = query->lastInsertId().toInt();
```

То `ret` тоже 0, даже если есть запись с `id` не равное 0
Что это может быть? Ведь с SQLITE,с тем же кодом все прекрасно работало.

Comment: Попробуйте такой вариант https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709117/qts-odbc-driver-does-not-support-lastinsertid-with-mysql-whats-the-workaround

Comment: а если убрать `:id` из `VALUES`?

Comment: Мне вот одно интересно, обещая системе передать 3 аргумента, а передавая 2, что Вы от неё ждёте?